# Get row of double match

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to find the row of the largest value by id for say jonny. I'm using excel 2016.

```
A      B
Ids  Figures
jonny  11
bob    37
jonny  2
bob    5
```

Between pivots and arrays I can get the largest figures, but finding row is where I fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a nested AGGREGATE function:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:$A$5)/(($A$2:$A$5="jonny")*(AGGREGATE(14,6,$B$2:$B$5/($A$2:$A$5="jonny"),1)=$B$2:$B$5)),1)
```

[image]

Comment: Ye that covers it, good thing I don't need more than 20 of these it looks massive.

Comment: Funny I thought getting the second largest was as easy as changing the [k]s. Can you give me a hand on that?

Comment: Just change the `k` on the inner aggregate only.  leave the outer as `1`

Comment: Apparently so, my bad - it failed before because some of the cell links were broken.